# When running pytest, ignore flag from addopts

Tags: python, shell, pytest

I have simple pytest.ini that defines (it's a django project, but django is irrelevant for merit of this question) that pytest should re-use the database.

It goes something like this:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --cov-config=pytest.ini --cov-report=html --no-cov-on-fail --cov=contact_management/ --ds=app.settings.test --reuse-db
```

For the most part --reuse-db works fine, but there are times that we want actually create and destroy the database when running test suite (when working on a new feature and not everything is set in stone for example).

We can set different --ds by repeating it in shell, ie.

```
pytest --ds=app.settings.better_test_settings
```

But is there a way to get rid of --reuse-db?

Pseudo-code would be like that:

```
pytest --ds=app.settings.better_test_settings --reuse-db=False
```

I found solution in form of using another pytest.ini with a flag -c but perhaps there is more elegant solution.